# DTD is prohibited in this XML document when using CSOM with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-online

This code snippet

```
string strUserName="abc";
string strPassword="123";
SecureString ssPwd = new SecureString();
strPassword.ToList().ForEach(ssPwd.AppendChar);
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteurl);
SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(strUserName, ssPwd);

context.Credentials = credentials;
// The SharePoint web at the URL.
Web web = context.Web;

// We want to retrieve the web's properties.
context.Load(web);

// Execute the query to the server.
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Creates the following error message trying to connect to SharePoint Online:

*For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.*

The same thing happens using the SharePoint Client Browser downloaded from CodePlex (https://spcb.codeplex.com).

What's wrong? What can I do?

Comment: Meanwhile I've found a solution for me. Change the DNS server on your network adapter card for example to 8.8.8.8 (Google) and it works fine.